# ROBLOX - cloned tool from replicated storage has a script not working

Tags: lua, roblox

I clone a tool from replicated storage and give it to the player's character where I can use it, but when I click with it it doesn't work, not even a print("Hey") works in the script. Why doesn't the script run? It works if I put it in starter pack but not clone it from replicated storage into workspace into the player's character, the script is present in the tool